# Python OneLogin: How to get all events using get_events?

Tags: python-3.x, onelogin

I'm using Python 3 to get information about past events through the OneLogin API. I use the `onelogin-python-sdk`, which I got from GitHub.

I can get events with `get_events`. However, only the number of data items specified in `max_results` can be retrieved. What should I do to get data that can reach tens of thousands?

Should I use another API?

```
import json
import csv
from optparse import OptionParser
from onelogin.api.client import OneLoginClient

query_parameters = {}

def get_options():
# Analyze Options
    return options

def format_eventdata(event_param):
#Formatting Dadta
    return(event_data)

def main():
    options = get_options()

    client = OneLoginClient(options.client_id, options.client_secret, 'US')
    events = client.get_events(query_parameters)

    with open(options.file, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        idx = 0
        if events:
            for data in events:
                eventdata=events[idx]
                csv_data = format_eventdata(eventdata)
                writer.writerow(csv_data)
                idx += 1
        else:
            print("end")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I just want to know how to get all the data without limit on the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself.
Adjusted the query parameters to reduce the amount of data retrieved at one time.

Thank you.